# Validation Drupal Form doesn't works

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, drupal-7

I created these two functions to be able to modify the validation of my Drupal form by following different subjects on SOF or other information. But my query never goes into the validate function, and I do not understand why ...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function *****_form_simplenews_block_form_1_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Modify some form settings
    $form['mail']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
    $form['mail']['#size'] = 40;
    $form['mail']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your email address');
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('OK');
    $form['#validate'][0] = '*****_simplenews_block_form_validate';
}

/**
 * Validate the mail address for simplenews
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param $form_state
 */
function *****_simplenews_block_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    kpr($form);die();
    if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['mail']) && $form_state['values']['check_robot']) {
        form_set_error('mail', t("Error, please try again"));
        form_set_error('submit', "You are a robot.");
    }
}
```

I went to see on the doc of the Drupal API (https://www.drupal.org/files/fapi_workflow_7.x_v1.1.png) , and it seems that I do what it is necessary, so if someone could help me, I would be rather happy, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bad !

The action form submit the form to a webservice. So it will never been validated by the Drupal form workflow.